# Spring Security OAuth2 Roles Not Working

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have the below application configured

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableResourceServer
@RestController
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@RequestMapping("/home")
public String home() {
    return "Hello World";
}

@RequestMapping("/reg/a")
public String reg() {
    return "REGISTERED";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public String create(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> map) {
    return "OK";
}

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("my-client-with-secret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "password")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read")
                .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
                .secret("secret");
    }

}}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class OAuth2WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean(name="authenticationManager")
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManager();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    String password = "pass";
    String user = "user";
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser(user).password(password).roles("USER")
        .and().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");

}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/reg/**")
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/reg/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')");
}
}
```

I am able to generate access token using below url with user/pass

> http://localhost:8080/oauth/token

And later

> http://localhost:8080/reg/a?access_token=bd280b8e-b0b0-47a7-96d9-b4f3bfa60692

is never blocked/thrown authorization error based on roles, I tried different ways like below, but nothing worked

> hasAccess("#oauth2.hasRole('ADMIN')"), hasAuthority('ADMIIN'),
>   hasRole('ADMIIN')

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: `RestController` should be segregated from `Auhtorization` server and `Resource` server. So create another class to handle request and annotate the class `@RestController`. Don't mix-up with `@EnableResourceServer`. let me know the status.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna Separating RestController didn't worked.

Comment: Did you generate `access_token` using this cred `user/pass` right? Now use `.withUser(user).password(password).roles("ROLE_USER")` instead of using `.withUser(user).password(password).roles("USER")`. Similar for ROLE_ADMIN instead of only `ADMIN`. For checking `.access("hasRole('ADMIN')")` is ok. Let me know the status.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna This as well didn't worked. If roles didn't match it shouldn't allow access at all. Problem is not with roles names, problem is roles are not considered at all.